# Dummy battery shells

Tags: batteries, power-supply

I have a device that takes two AA batteries and I want to replace it with my own external power source and regulation circuitry. Instead of clipping or soldering wires to the device contacts, I would rather plug in a dummy battery shell that has the appropriate contacts on the end to make the whole project cleaner and more prototype friendly.

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could almost DIY something out of birch dowel and a couple of small pointy-ended screws, the only thing would be getting the dimensions right. You could even hide the low-tec materials by covering the whole assemblage with heat-shrink tubing.

Comment: I was hoping for something a bit more polished so it is possible to travel with it. I don't want to risk the hassles of having some sketchy looking homemade electronics when flying.

Comment: @SteveP I've flown many times with sketch home made electronics. As long as it doesn't look or smell like explosives, you should be fine. You might get "randomly selected" for the extra special screening a little more often though.

Comment: I ended up ordering this type of dummy AAA to AA converter off of ebay:

http://www.sourcingmap.com/battery-holder-converter-adaptor-size-aaa-p-34409.html

It doesn't have the bottom connector, but the sizing will be right and I can easily wire two together given the shell is empty.

Comment: @SteveP - you know, you're probably only going to need one wire into each fake battery; if the device takes two, it most likely wants 3V, and two of the contacts in the battery compartment will just be bridged, so you'll need to determine which ends the device takes the power from, and wire to the corresponding battery ends.

Comment: @SteveP: Good thinking.  I like the writeup on that site: *When you need use AA battery, but actually you only got a piece of AAA battery, than how? You will not worry about this sort of question with this Battery Holder Converter. It features a piece AAA battery can be used as a AA battery. Easy and your life will become more convenient.*

Comment: http://www.allnewsmac.com/2010/08/20/replace-magic-trackpad-batteries-with-a-diy-usb-cable/

Answer (score 4):

There are a few models for 3d printable battery shells up on thingiverse:

http://dev.thingiverse.com/tag:batteries

You could probably modify these designs to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that wooden dowel is probably your quickest way to success, but if that's too sketch for you I don't think you need to jump to a 3D printer.  Make a silicone mold of two batteries in the configuration you need and use something like Alumilite or ShapeLock (or any modelling material, I've used both of those and you can get some pretty awesome results) to make a plastic part that looks great and fits perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Search Internet for 'AA to AAA adapters'. They're basically empty shells, the size of a regular penlight. They also exist for C and D type cells and are normally used to fit a smaller sized cell in your equipment than it was designed for. The AA-size ones are about $1.50 for 4pcs. They're made of plastic and you can easily drill a little hole in them to connect a wire to the terminal.

Comment: Hmm .. just noticed you figured this one yourself

Comment: If you have a price I guess you also have a reference. Care to share a link? (GIYF or anything like it is not a good answer)

Comment: You got me, they'just over 1.50 *Euro's* (€1.91) and $2.30 for 4 pcs. http://www.dealextreme.com/p/translucent-aaa-to-aa-type-battery-converter-cases-4-case-54457

Answer (score 1):

JustJeff's comment gave me an idea:

> @SteveP - you know, you're probably
>   only going to need one wire into each
>   fake battery; if the device takes two,
>   it most likely wants 3V, and two of
>   the contacts in the battery
>   compartment will just be bridged, so
>   you'll need to determine which ends
>   the device takes the power from, and
>   wire to the corresponding battery
>   ends.

A simple extension of this proposal would be to use two dead (Or fresh, if you like) batteries, put a piece of electrical tape (or otherwise disable) the bridged end of one battery, and then solder/conductive glue your wires onto the caps of the real batteries. This won't work if the batteries are in parallel, or if something is monitoring/drawing off of the middle of the battery pack, but JustJeff is right - most devices are wired in series.

An alternative would be to (permanently, sorry) solder a short pair of wires with a connector onto the back side of the device contacts (or PCB), and then remove the batteries and plug into the PSU.  When you want the prototype look to go away (or you want to travel through an airport), you can simply tuck the connector back into the case, and put in normal batteries.  However, I understand the hesitation to touch your (possibly expensive) device with a soldering iron!

Comment: i almost suggested just soldering the power leads to small metal disks, which could be pressed in place by an actual battery, with a piece of plastic stuck in on the other end. could use a dead battery, but then there's the risk of caustic ooze. but as you say, fresh will do. a fresh, ordinary carbon-zinc dry cell would be ultra cheap and very long lasting in this setup.

Answer (score 1):

It appears [it exists](http://www.adorama.com/QTES2.html), and is called a "dummy battery".  But at $7 each, I think I'd opt for JustJeff's dowel-rod route.

Comment: That dummy cell is meant to be put in a camera flash instead of an AA cell, so for it to still work, the dummy can't be an open circuit inside.  It might be a short between the two terminals, or some kind of circuit, who knows what.  Could still be useful mechanically if you cut it open, but you would not want to put voltage across the two terminals without knowing what's inside first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just connect the power cables of your device to AC adapters by soldering the appropriate leads and heat-shrinking the solder joints.